# If two applications are using same workbooks at a time then tool in unable to close those workbooks(vba)

Tags: vba, excel

My `VBA` application updates some `.xls` files(as database files) from .csv files(as raw files).
To update those .xls file application looks for some information in lookup files(.xls files) and updates in database. If I am running the same application from different folder to update different database files but using the same lookup files, application is working fine but at last it is unable to close all the lookup files and raw files.
And application is also not throwing any exception.
I am opening these lookup file in READ ONLY mode. How to close these file without saving them ?
Please give suggestions on this issue

Actually I am running the tool from windows scheduler so it automatically closes every thing when the process is complete. But what I am obseving is that the tool is not closing these files:
- 3 lookup files from which tool is extracting(reading) some information to update database files.
- Raw file which was opened at last.
- Last opened database file

To open lookup files and raw files, I am using below code
Set Wbk_MachinLookUp_SN = Workbooks.Open(FileNameandExt, , ReadOnly:=True)

To open database files:
Set wbk_dtc_Month = Workbooks.Open(FilenameWith_Path)

I am closing lookup and raw file without saving them, and the code is:

```
Public Sub CloseAllFiles()
 Dim StrName As String
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 On Error Resume Next

    StrName = ToCheckExtention(Form_TopLevel.TextBox_SubSystem_LookUp, 1)
    If Module2.IsXLBookOpen(StrName) = True Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Wbk_SubSystem.Close Savechanges:=False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Set Wbk_SubSystem = Nothing
    End If

    StrName = ToCheckExtention(Form_TopLevel.TextBox_MachineSN_LookUp, 1)
    If Module2.IsXLBookOpen(StrName) = True Then
        Wbk_MachinLookUp_SN.Close Savechanges:=False
        Set Wbk_MachinLookUp_SN = Nothing
    End If

    StrName = ToCheckExtention(Form_TopLevel.TextBox_SwPn_Rel_LookUp, 1)
    If Module2.IsXLBookOpen(StrName) = True Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Wbk_SW_ReleseasesLookup.Close Savechanges:=False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Set Wbk_SW_ReleseasesLookup = Nothing
    End If

    StrName = ToCheckExtention(Form_TopLevel.TextBox_SwPn_ESI_BR, 1)
    If Module2.IsXLBookOpen(StrName) = True Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Module2.Wbk_sw_pn.Close Savechanges:=False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Set Wbk_sw_pn = Nothing
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub

Function ToCheckExtention(Str As String, Flag As Byte) As String

Dim IndexNo As Integer
Dim temp As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
IndexNo = InStr(Str, "\")
If IndexNo <> 0 Then
    temp = StrReverse(Str)
    IndexNo = InStr(temp, "\")
    Str = VBA.MID(temp, 1, IndexNo - 1)
    Str = StrReverse(Str)
End If

    IndexNo = InStr(Str, ".")
    If IndexNo <> 0 Then
        temp = VBA.MID(Str, IndexNo + 1, Len(Str))
        If temp = "xls" Or temp = "csv" Then
            ToCheckExtention = Str
            Exit Function
        End If
    ElseIf IndexNo = 0 Then
        If Flag = 1 Then
            Str = Str & ".xls"
            ToCheckExtention = Str
            Exit Function
        ElseIf Flag = 0 Then
            Str = Str & ".csv"
            ToCheckExtention = Str
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
ToCheckExtention = Str
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Function


Function IsXLBookOpen(StrName As String) As Boolean
Dim i As Long, XLAppFx As Excel.Application, NotOpen As Boolean
Dim IndexNo As Integer
Dim temp As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 'Find/create an Excel instance

IndexNo = InStr(StrName, "\")
If IndexNo <> 0 Then
    temp = StrReverse(StrName)
    IndexNo = InStr(temp, "\")
    StrName = VBA.MID(temp, 1, IndexNo - 1)
    StrName = StrReverse(StrName)
End If

On Error Resume Next
Set XLAppFx = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err.Number = 429 Then
    NotOpen = True
    Set XLAppFx = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Err.Clear
End If

 'Loop through all open workbooks in such instance
For i = XLAppFx.Workbooks.Count To 1 Step -1
    If XLAppFx.Workbooks(i).Name = StrName Then Exit For
Next i

 'Set all to False
IsXLBookOpen = False

 'Perform check to see if name was found
If i <> 0 Then IsXLBookOpen = True

 'Close if was closed
If NotOpen Then XLAppFx.Quit

 'Release the instance
Set XLAppFx = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Function
```

To close database files(I am saving all database files), here is the code:

```
With wbk_dtc_Month
If Version > 11 Then
   .SaveAs FileName:=BuildFolderAndFileName, FileFormat:=56
Else
   .SaveAs FileName:=BuildFolderAndFileName
End If
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   .Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End With
Set wbk_dtc_Month = Nothing
```

Comment: we need to see some code

Comment: Can you give more details? How do you know they are not closed? What is the code that tries to close, but apparently does not close the excel-files? How are they opened? etc... We need to understand your problem to be able to help.

Comment: I have edited my post for your reference.

Comment: The raw files, are you opening them into an Excel object I take it?  If so, rather than trying to parse all open Excel instances, assign an object varaible to them before you open the files.  That removes one possible disconnect.

Comment: The workbooks which are not getting closed are only lookup files. And I am creating a different objects for different lookup files. Also I am using excel objects to open and close lookup files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue of not closing all files.
I have done modification in function "Function IsXLBookOpen"

The change is:

```
Function IsXLBookOpen(StrName As String) As Boolean

Dim oBk As Workbook
On Error Resume Next
Set oBk = Workbooks(StrName)
On Error GoTo 0
If oBk Is Nothing Then
    IsXLBookOpen = False
Else
    IsXLBookOpen = True
End If

End Function
```

Earlier function was not returning the right value if I open files in read only mode.